# How to see what's in hibernate first level cache (the Hibernate Session) in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Context :

A project using SpringBoot + Hibernate

Let's say we have the following UserService :

```
@Service
public class UserService {

  private final UserRepository userRepository;

  public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
  }
  
  public void doSomething() {
    User user = User.builder()
            .firstname("firstname")
            .lastname("lastname")
            .build();
    userRepository.save(user);
    

    user.setAge(23L);
    userRepository.save(user);
  }

}
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to see what's in the first level hibernate cache(The Session) when I am debugging the doSomething() method. For example, if I set a break point at the level of the `user.setAge(23L);` line, which means i already called the save method once, how can I see the user value already cached by the Hibernate session at this point ?

Answer (score 0):

In codes , the L1 cache is represented by `PersistenceContext` which you can get it from the following codes given an `EntityManager`:

```java
@Service
public class UserService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    public void doSomething() {

         PersistenceContext firstLevelCache =  entityManager.unwrap(SessionImpl.class).getPersistenceContextInternal();

   }

}
```

You can then play around its API or even cast it to its only one implementation `StatefulPersistenceContext` if necessary to see if it can achieve your need.